# Swift Convert unix timezone to local

Tags: json, swift

Im making a request to a weather API to get some weather data. The issue is how to make sense of the timezone they are providing. Here is a snippet from JSON

```
"timezone": -14400 // How do you interpret this?,
"id": 5128581,
"name": "New York",
"cod": 200
```

Is there a way in Swift to convert this `timezone` so it could be used to display the current time in New York relative to your local timezone?

Comment: Well, how you interpret a response from an API would depend on what the documentation of said API says. But 14400 seconds is 4 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to parse your json string and then you can use `DateFormatter` initializing its `timeZone` property with that value using the `secondsFromGMT` initializer:

```
let timezone = -14400

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timezone)
dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // "6:39 PM"
```